# Prove the inequality $\sum^m_{k=0} {n\choose k}\leq \left ( \frac{en}{m} \right)^m$

Tags: combinatorics, inequality, binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

When doing some exercises in probability, I was faced with the question to prove the following inequality:
$$\sum^m_{k=0} {n\choose k}\leq \left ( \frac{en}{m} \right)^m, \forall m\leq n \in \mathbb N$$

I was not able to come up with a solution, but found this one [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3044044/how-to-prove-upper-bound-for-partial-sum-of-binomial-coefficients). The thing is, the exercise came with the following tip: "multiply both sides by $(m/n)^m$, replace this by $(m/n)^k$ on the lhs, and use the binomial theorem".

I was wondering if someone was able to prove this inequality actually using this tip.

Comment: that is different from the formula in the link; do you mean for the right hand side to be $(en/m)^n$ instead?

Comment: Yeah, just noticed the mistake. Just fixed it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Multiplying

$$\sum_{k=0}^m\binom{n}k\le\left(\frac{en}m\right)^m$$

on both sides by $\left(\frac{m}n\right)^m$ results in the equivalent inequality

$$\left(\frac{m}n\right)^m\sum_{k=0}^m\binom{n}k\le\left(\frac{m}n\right)^m\left(\frac{en}m\right)^m=e^m\;.$$

Now

$$\begin{align*}
\left(\frac{m}n\right)^m\sum_{k=0}^m\binom{n}k&=\sum_{k=0}^m\left(\frac{m}n\right)^m\binom{n}k\\
&\le\sum_{k=0}^m\left(\frac{m}n\right)^k\binom{n}k\quad\left(\text{since }\frac{m}n\le 1\right)\\
&\le\sum_{k=0}^n\left(\frac{m}n\right)^k\binom{n}k\\
&=\left(1+\frac{m}n\right)^n\\
&\le e^{\frac{m}n\cdot n}=e^m\;,
\end{align*}$$

as desired.

Comment: I just don't follow the last inequality, $(1+m/n)^n \leq e^m$

Comment: @DaviBarreira: See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli%27s_inequality#Related_inequalities).

Answer (score 2):

Hint: use the hint until it says "use the binomial theorem". Instead use
$$
\binom{n}{k} \le \frac{{n^k }}{{k!}}
$$
and the Taylor series of the exponential function.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I proved this inequality above, but couldn't finish the proof.

Comment: @DaviBarreira We have $$
 \left( {\frac{m}{n}} \right)^m \sum\limits_{k = 0}^m \binom{n}{k}  = \sum\limits_{k = 0}^m \left( {\frac{m}{n}} \right)^m \binom{n}{k}  \le \sum\limits_{k = 0}^m {\left( {\frac{m}{n}} \right)^k \binom{n}{k}}  \\  \le \sum\limits_{k = 0}^m {\left( {\frac{m}{n}} \right)^k \frac{{n^k }}{{k!}}}  = \sum\limits_{k = 0}^m {\frac{{m^k }}{{k!}}}  \le \sum\limits_{k = 0}^\infty  {\frac{{m^k }}{{k!}}}  = e^m .
$$

Answer (score 1):

You want to show
$$\left(\frac mn\right)^m \sum_{k=0}^m{n\choose k}\leq e^m$$
But
$$\left(\frac mn\right)^m \sum_{k=0}^m{n\choose k}=  \sum_{k=0}^m\left(\frac mn\right)^m{n\choose k}\leq \sum_{k=0}^m\left(\frac mn\right)^k{n\choose k} \leq \sum_{k=0}^n\left(\frac mn\right)^k{n\choose k} =\left(1+\frac{m}{n}\right)^n$$
since $m\le n$, so $m/n\le 1$, and the last equality is the binomial theorem.

But for every $x\ge 0$, one has $(1+\frac xn)^n \leq e^x$, so
$$(1+\frac{m}{n})^n\leq e^m$$
and we are done.

Comment: Why $(1 + x/n)^n \leq e^x$? Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Since $\lim_{n\to \infty}(1+\frac xn)^n=e^x$ and $(1+\frac xn)^n$ is monotonally increasing.

Comment: Thanks, friend! I accepted the other answer, because the user answered first.